# Why do structured bindings not support variadics?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

C++17 adds structured bindings:

```
tuple<int, int, int> make_tuple();
int test() {
    auto [a, b, c] = make_tuple();
    return a | b | c;
}
```

My immediate instinct was to try using them as parameter packs.

```
template <size_t N>
auto make_tuple();  // returns tuple with N ints
template <size_t N>
int test() {
    auto [...values] = make_tuple<N>();
    return (0 | ... | values);
}
```

Alas, I cannot do this. Why did the committee exclude such functionality? It feels inconsistent now that lambda captures can contain parameter packs.

I know the committee is full of intelligent creative people, and an idea like mine must have come up and been rejected for good reason. What is that reason?

Comment: Unrelated: But saying "_I know the committee is full of intelligent creative people_" in this kind of context makes it sound like you mean the opposite.

Comment: Assuming they had the idea is not an assumption you should make.  Stuff gets left out all the time.  You should join the standard proposal group and float your idea.

Comment: [P1061](https://wg21.link/p1061).

Comment: I don't mean the opposite, and the vast majority of the times I made this assumption I turned out to be right. Also happy 2020.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the nature of a developing language that features be added over time.

Just because something is not in the language yet, does not mean that the committee already rejected it outright. It does not mean that they "excluded" it. It could just be that it was overlooked, or just hadn't been seriously considered yet. Remember, `std::make_unique` wasn't available until C++14.

In this particular case, it's a feature that *has* been proposed, quite recently, as [P1061](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1061r1.html). You'll note from the revision history section that the committee *"reviewed it favorably and thought this was a good investment of our time"*. So I guess you're in luck. :)

Comment: Thanks for the research. I believe cases where a feature was overlooked or unintentionally left out are rare. Most times, a feature is either intentionally excluded permanently, or intentionally excluded temporarily, both for good reason. I believe the latter applies to the current case, and would like to know the reason why.